# How to use data-source profiles after creating in spring

Tags: spring

I know how to configure multiple data-sources with profiles but how to make use particular data-source. Assume In development I want to use development profile data-source and in production, I want to use production profile data-source. Below is the code with multiple profile configuration but how to activate particular profile and use it.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
@Profile("development")
@Bean
public DataSource embeddedDataSource() {
return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
.addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
.addScript("classpath:test-data.sql")
.build();
}
@Profile("qa")
@Bean
public DataSource Data() {
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/spitter");
ds.setUsername("sa");
ds.setPassword("");
ds.setInitialSize(5);
ds.setMaxActive(10);
return ds;
}
@Profile("production")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean
= new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/SpittrDS");
jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
return (DataSource) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to start your application with parameter :

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

More informations here :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles